# Linux command for verbose gc

Tags: linux, performance, garbage-collection, command, verbosegc

A very simple question, Am a brand new guy to linux scripting,

I just want to know, How to make the following command to add and run in my linux script.

```
-Xloggc:C:\whereever\jvm.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
```

I know its a silly question, But please I need an immediate solution for this. Just want to know how to add this in the script???

If possible please do let me know, how to see that verbose gc log collection is running in my system.

Comment: What command are you talking about? You need to post your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a good example for you.
[Verbose gc in linux](http://freddyandersen.wordpress.com/2009/07/14/how-to-enable-verbose-gc-in-tomcat/)

Comment: Thank you! My script is passing nw! How to check that whether the verbose:gc is running nw??